# How can I retrieve CASE output in the same column with AVG function output?

Tags: sql

I need to retrieve department name and average salary in each department except case when there are no employees in department, in that case the output should be 0 in the same column as average salary. [Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRSYJ.png).

Firstly I wrote the code :

```
SELECT Department.NAME, AVG(Employee.salary) as avg_slr,
CASE 
WHEN Employee.ID IS NULL
THEN 0 
END 
FROM Department
LEFT JOIN Employee ON Department.ID = Employee.department_ID
GROUP BY Department.NAME, Employee.ID
```

As expected, CASE construction creates another column but how can I avoid it and keep only two columns in output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just default the NULL averages to 0

```
SELECT Department.NAME
, COALESCE(AVG(Employee.salary), 0) as avg_slr
FROM Department
LEFT JOIN Employee ON Department.ID = Employee.department_ID
GROUP BY Department.NAME
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0b90a4204133f847d5d6ef55edb976f8)*

Note that it is possible to wrap the `AVG` in a `CASE WHEN`.
But a `CASE WHEN` would be more useful for complexer logic.

```
SELECT Department.NAME
, CASE
  WHEN AVG(Employee.salary) IS NOT NULL
  THEN AVG(Employee.salary) 
  ELSE 0
  END as avg_slr
FROM Department
LEFT JOIN Employee ON Department.ID = Employee.department_ID
GROUP BY Department.NAME
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not know about the function, will read about it.

Comment: @Chowis A `COALESCE` can accept many parameters and will return the value of the first in the list that has a value. It's standard ANSI SQL.